# How do I type š on an international keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, internationalization

I'm currently writing emails frequently to a Slovenian who has the letter š in his name. I use copy and paste for the letter š, which is quite inconvenient.

I'm using the US keyboard layout.

How can I type this letter directly from the keyboard?

Comment: which keyboard layout are you using?

Comment: @Agos US keyboard layout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right Option (Alt) v s

You must have U.S. Extended keyboard layout enabled for the above to work.

Comment: That did it, after turning on US Extended keyboard layout. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can choose edit menu (in most software)  then choose `Special Character ..` then go to `Accented Latin` tab and find your character `Š`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a direct way of typing this on the keyboard, just like I do alt+u o to get ö and alt+n n to get ñ

Answer (score 3):

Simply hold down the S key and you'll be presented with three options - press 3 on your keyboard to type š. If you need a capital Š just use the Shift Key or Caps Lock.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the patience to configure the keybindings, you can try [Ukelele](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/14495/ukelele) and create a keyboard layout for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not near my iMac right now, so I can't test this. But this usually works for me http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.5/en/8504.html

Answer (score 1):

I have long had the same problem. My solution: install the Slovenian keyboard layout and set the shortcut to changing between keyboards to Option+Tab. That works very quickly and gives you all the special letters (they are in place of the paranthesis and quotation keys on an English keyboard.)